# To Control ExpandableList by adding onclick listener event.

Tags: android

I have created a  custom Expandable list when i click on it,  will move to child items,
Can i control the expandable list using click listener (Example if i click on one of the group item it should go to other view(Layout) rather than going on child items 
This is my code

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {

        private ExpandListAdapter ExpAdapter;
        private ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> ExpListItems;
        private ExpandableListView ExpandList;
        Header1 header;
        ExpandableList ExpandableList;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            header = (Header1)findViewById(R.id.header);
            header.initHeader();
            ExpandableList = (ExpandableList)findViewById(R.id.Expanadable);
            ExpandableList.Expandableview();
            ExpandList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.ExpList);
            ExpListItems = SetStandardGroups();
            ExpAdapter = new ExpandListAdapter(MainActivity.this, ExpListItems);
            ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);
        }

        public ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> SetStandardGroups() {
            ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> list = new ArrayList<ExpandListGroup>();
            ArrayList<ExpandListChild> list2 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();
            ArrayList<ExpandListChild> list3 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();

            ExpandListGroup gru1 = new ExpandListGroup();
            gru1.setName("Employee Search");

            ExpandListChild ch1_1 = new ExpandListChild();
            ch1_1.setName("First Name");
            ch1_1.setTag(null);
            list2.add(ch1_1);

            ExpandListChild ch1_2 = new ExpandListChild();
            ch1_2.setName("Last Name");
            ch1_2.setTag(null);
            list2.add(ch1_2);

            ExpandListChild ch1_3 = new ExpandListChild();
            ch1_3.setName("Email ID");
            ch1_3.setTag(null);
            list2.add(ch1_3);

            ExpandListChild ch1_4 = new ExpandListChild();
            ch1_4.setName("Associate ID");
            ch1_4.setTag(null);
            list2.add(ch1_4);
            gru1.setItems(list2);
            list2 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();

            ExpandListGroup gru2 = new ExpandListGroup();
            gru2.setName("Working Time");

            ExpandListChild ch2_1 = new ExpandListChild();
            ch2_1.setName("Leave Request");
            ch2_1.setTag(null);
            list2.add(ch2_1);

            ExpandListGroup gru4 = new ExpandListGroup();
            gru4.setName("Leave Request");
            list3 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();
            ExpandListChild ch21_1 = new ExpandListChild();
            ch21_1.setName("create Leave");
            ch21_1.setTag(null);
            list3.add(ch21_1);
            gru4.setItems(list3);

            ExpandListChild ch2_2 = new ExpandListChild();
            ch2_2.setName("CATS Regular/Record Working time");
            ch2_2.setTag(null);
            list2.add(ch2_2);

           /* ExpandListChild ch2_3 = new ExpandListChild();
            ch2_3.setName("And an other movie");
            ch2_3.setTag(null);
            list2.add(ch2_3);*/
            gru2.setItems(list2);

            list2 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();
            ExpandListGroup gru3 = new ExpandListGroup();
            gru3.setName("Travel and Expenses");

            ExpandListChild ch3_1 = new ExpandListChild();
            ch3_1.setName("Travel Request");
            ch3_1.setTag(null);
            list2.add(ch3_1);

            ExpandListChild ch3_2 = new ExpandListChild();
            ch3_2.setName("Travel Expenses");
            ch3_2.setTag(null);
            list2.add(ch3_2);
            gru3.setItems(list2);

            list.add(gru1);
            list.add(gru2);
            list.add(gru3);

            return list;
        }

    }
```

Now if i click on the "employeesearch" group it should move to another layout. And keeping the remaining group as same as the expandable list. Below is the Adapter class.

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter  {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> groups;
    public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> groups) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    public void addItem(ExpandListChild item, ExpandListGroup group) {
        if (!groups.contains(group)) {
            groups.add(group);
        }
        int index = groups.indexOf(group);
        ArrayList<ExpandListChild> ch = groups.get(index).getItems();
        ch.add(item);
        groups.get(index).setItems(ch);
    }
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<ExpandListChild> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        return chList.get(childPosition);
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childPosition;
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        ExpandListChild child = (ExpandListChild) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_child_item, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvChild);
        tv.setText(child.getName().toString());
        tv.setTag(child.getTag());
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return view;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<ExpandListChild> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();

        return chList.size();

    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groups.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        ExpandListGroup group = (ExpandListGroup) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inf.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_group_item, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvGroup);
        tv.setText(group.getName());
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return view;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a good use for `onGroupClick`

From the docs:

```
public abstract boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id)
 Since: API Level 1
Callback method to be invoked when a group in this expandable list has been clicked.
Parameters
parent            The ExpandableListConnector where the click happened
v                 The view within the expandable list/ListView that was clicked
groupPosition     The group position that was clicked
id                The row id of the group that was clicked
```